# PHP handler for SQL Error 1022

Tags: php, sql

Can someone help me with my SQL query/php handler?

I'm trying to customise the error message for mysql_errno() 1022 so that it says "Serial Number already exists" rather than saying "Error: Duplicate entry 'TEST' for key 'ser'".

I've tried changing the handler to the following but had no joy.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1022) {
        die("Username already exists");
    } else {
        die("Error:" . mysql_error($con));
    }
}
```

My code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "assets");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO barts (project, system, ser, assets, tdate) VALUES ('$_POST[element_3]','$_POST[element_4]','$_POST[element_1]','$_POST[element_2]','$_POST[tdate]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `mysqli_query()` (mind the 'i') but then you check the error code with the regular/deprecated `mysql_errno()` function. In addition you need to pass the connection to use (`$con`).

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    if (mysqli_errno($con) == 1022) {
        die("Username already exists");
    } else {
        die('Error:' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn it, always ends up being something you should have spotted yourself. Thanks very much for your help. :)